# How to check User Status (Online/Offline) in firebase v9 using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database

I Have made one chat application, i need to display user status (offline, online) and he gets disconnects, window/tab or logouts in firebase v9

firebase.js

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getDatabase } from 'firebase/database';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: apikey,
  authDomain: 'xxxxx.firebaseapp.com',
  projectId: 'xxxx',
  storageBucket: 'xxxx.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: 'xxxxxx',
  appId: '1:xxxxxxxx:web:xxxxxxx',
};

export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth();
export const storage = getStorage();
export const db = getFirestore();
export const firebaseDb = getDatabase(app);
```

Added firebase chat db

[image]

This is what I have tried but not working I guess (im new to firebase)

```
  useEffect(() => {
        const connectedRef = ref(firebaseDb, '.info/connected');
        const uid = '3bEw4VqpMieSzR8NBfDz6XqG33l1';
        const myConnectionsRef = ref(firebaseDb, 'users', uid);
        console.log(myConnectionsRef, 'myConnectionsRef');
        onValue(connectedRef, (snap) => {
          console.log(snap.val(), 'snap');
          if (snap.val() === true) {
            console.log('TRUE');
            if (user) {
              set(myConnectionsRef, 'connected');
              updateFirestoreUser(user, true);
            }
          } else {
            console.log('FALSE');
            updateFirestoreUser(user, false);
          }
          //onDisconnect(myConnectionsRef)
          //.set("disconnected")
          //.then(() => {
          //   updateFirestoreUser(user, false);
          //});
        });
    
      }, []);
```

Updated: snap().value is showing false even if provided uuid is online.
[image]

Db ss of uid:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have read your code quickly, and I have figured out the problem you should select the `online` item, but you didn't select it instead you have selected the whole object which will always return true because the object exists.
This is how you can fix it:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const db = getDatabase();
    const uid = '3bEw4VqpMieSzR8NBfDz6XqG33l1';
    const myConnectionsRef = refs(db, 'users', uid);
    console.log(myConnectionsRef, 'myConnectionsRef');
    onValue(myConnectionsRef, (snap) => {
      console.log(snap, 'snap');
      if (snap.val().online === true) {
       // We're connected (or reconnected)! Do anything here that should happen only if 
        online (or on reconnect)
        const con = push(myConnectionsRef);
        console.log('hi', con);
        // When I disconnect, remove this device
        onDisconnect(con).remove();

        // Add this device to my connections list
        // this value could contain info about the device or a timestamp too
        set(con, true);

        // When I disconnect, update the last time I was seen online
        onDisconnect(lastOnlineRef).set(serverTimestamp());
      }
    });

  }, []);
```

Also note if you change the value you may need to adjust it too.

Comment: Thanks for reply, when i use above code, snap.val() is showing false even if the provided userid is online and if i give snap.val().online, it throws undefined, i have  shared the screenshot above

Comment: can you share the DB for the user `3bEw4VqpMieSzR8NBfDz6XqG33l1` since you are sharing another document, but your code is checking that document. it could be that the `online` doesn't exist there. Because it should work according to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write) it is correct

Comment: i have shared ss of that  user 3bEw4VqpMieSzR8NBfDz6XqG33l1 in my original post